# Python: Printing custom message after importing library / module

Tags: python, python-2.x

I have a web-app on which user will be writing a Python snippet.

I want to add a custom message whenever user imports a library. For example, if user's code is something as below

```
import pandas
import os
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
```

Then the output should have:

```
You have imported pandas
You have imported os
You have imported Popen
You have imported PIPE
```

The user's code can be dynamic, and can actually import any library.

Answer (score 2):

The only way I can think of right now is to use try except. You can take user input (the library name) as string and then:

```
import importlib

lib_to_import = 'math'


try:
    importlib.import_module(lib_to_import)
    print("You have imported {}.".format(lib_to_import))
except:
    print("Something went wrong when importing {}.".format(lib_to_import))
```

You can wrap the above into a function and call it every time when the user imports a library.

Comment: The user's code can be dynamic, and can actually import any library. Updated the same in the question.

Comment: @UtsavKesharwani I have updated my answer. If `importlib.import_module(lib_to_import)` fails due to either import process error or no module exist, it will go to except.